# Why maven cannot add my dependency to jar?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I'm new to maven and one simple thing I wanted to do is pull maven repository and use it in my project.
but this has happened.

> pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ToolsQA</groupId>

  <artifactId>jutil_table</artifactId>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>jutil_table</name>

  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.chrisgleissner</groupId>
      <artifactId>jutil-protobuf</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.11</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

> App.java

```java
package ToolsQA;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */

 import static com.github.chrisgleissner.jutil.table.TablePrinter.DefaultTablePrinter;
 import static java.util.Arrays.asList;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
         Iterable<String> HEADERS = asList("id", "name", "age");
         DefaultTablePrinter.print(HEADERS, null);
    }
}
```

> Complete Error message

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< ToolsQA:jutil_table >-------------------------
[INFO] Building jutil_table 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ jutil_table ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Pawar\Desktop\mvn_tutorial\jutil_table\jutil_table\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jutil_table ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Pawar\Desktop\mvn_tutorial\jutil_table\jutil_table\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ jutil_table ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Pawar\Desktop\mvn_tutorial\jutil_table\jutil_table\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pawar/Desktop/mvn_tutorial/jutil_table/jutil_table/src/main/java/ToolsQA/App.java:[8,53] package com.github.chrisgleissner.jutil.table does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pawar/Desktop/mvn_tutorial/jutil_table/jutil_table/src/main/java/ToolsQA/App.java:[8,2] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pawar/Desktop/mvn_tutorial/jutil_table/jutil_table/src/main/java/ToolsQA/App.java:[18,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable DefaultTablePrinter
  location: class ToolsQA.App
[INFO] 3 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.037 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-24T22:49:15+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project jutil_table: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pawar/Desktop/mvn_tutorial/jutil_table/jutil_table/src/main/java/ToolsQA/App.java:[8,53] package com.github.chrisgleissner.jutil.table does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pawar/Desktop/mvn_tutorial/jutil_table/jutil_table/src/main/java/ToolsQA/App.java:[8,2] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pawar/Desktop/mvn_tutorial/jutil_table/jutil_table/src/main/java/ToolsQA/App.java:[18,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable DefaultTablePrinter
[ERROR]   location: class ToolsQA.App
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I read lot of articles and lot of related questions on stackoverflow about this. but still maven is unable to download the repo. and build is failing.
I used mvn compile, mvn package, mvn clean install nothing worked for me.
Please help✌️

Comment: Do you see `jutil-protobuf` jar in your local repo? If you open it, do you see `DefaultTablePrinter` class file?

Comment: Is that version available in maven central (if you are using that as repo )? In maven central I see version upto 1.1.9 only and not 1.1.11 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.chrisgleissner/jutil-protobuf

Comment: @MukeshKeshu If you correctly use the central search engine you will see https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.chrisgleissner/jutil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/chrisgleissner/jutil/blob/master/README.md), you need to have all three dependencies. That issue you have posted is not directly relevant to maven. That says the compiler cannot find symbols, may be because the class is not there in the classpath. Try with all the dependencies included.

Or in this case, what you really need the dependency for `jutil-table` only. You can omit the other two. But your maven pom contain `jutil-protobuf` dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.chrisgleissner</groupId>
    <artifactId>jutil-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.chrisgleissner</groupId>
    <artifactId>jutil-sql-log</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.chrisgleissner</groupId>
    <artifactId>jutil-table</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

And build the jar including the dependencies using maven assembly plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass> // Main class Ex : com.Test </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: mvn clean install should do it. Let me know if it is fixed

Comment: mvn clean install and mvn package successfully executed build success.  but when I run `java -cp target/jutil_table-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ToolsQA.App` it gives me `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/chrisgleissner/jutil/table/TablePrinter at ToolsQA.App.main(App.java:18)`

Comment: @Klaus `install` is usually not needed. Either `mvn package` or if you have integration tests `mvn verify`...

Comment: @AashishPawar seems like your jar is built without the dependencies. Use maven assembly plugin and buils with dependencies. See my updated answer

Comment: I always consider mvn install similar to npm install but it not , Right ?

Comment: I added  as you said . after that I run mvn clean install but still it says NoClassFoundError  com.github.chrisgleissner.jutil.table.TablePrinter

Comment: @AashishPawar Having both maven assembly plugin and maven jar plugin makes confusion. You only need maven assembly plugin and above three dependencies. Make sure to add the Main class in assembly plugin. Then do a clean package. That should do it.

Comment: I have only two plugins in my pom.xml compiler plugin and assembly plugin